# Mongoose aggregate doesn't return unmatched subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have subdocuments inside documents. And I'm trying to get entire documents if any subdocument provides multiple conditions. It's working right except not showing unmatched subdocuments.

```
# EXAMPLE DOCUMENT
name: "Sam",
specs: [
  {city: "istanbul", color: "blue"},
  {city: "istanbul", color: "black"},
  {city: "izmir", color: "yellow"}
]
```

```
# QUERY
Dudes.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$specs'},
    {$match: {'specs.city': "istanbul", 'specs.color': "yellow"} }
  ]);
```

It's returning the matching documents but in documents there is only matched subdocument.

```
# OUTPUT:
name: "Sam",
specs: [
  {city: "izmir", color: "yellow"}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1GF0ErYNEk

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to match object inside the array element.

```
db.collection.find({
  specs: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "city": "istanbul",
      "color": "blue"
    }
  }
});
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Wr1L6i2dipP

You can directly use `$match` and remove  `{$unwind: '$specs'}`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "specs.city": "istanbul",
      "specs.color": "blue"
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: unfortunetely, it's not worked in that way.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/bt3cDQZWKxL check this out please.

when we delete the unwind, it returns Sam too.
But it have to match if subdocument is {city: "istanbuk", "color": "blue"}

in this example only Matt is matching

Comment: @TanerTunçer Updated answer check, https://mongoplayground.net/p/2CeiKnajRlS

Comment: Something going wrong. It says no document found in your example

Comment: @TanerTunçer Check in your local setup,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUDgw.png

Comment: This is so weird.. Even in mongoplayground, it's says no document found, I'm clicking couple times and run again, then it's finds document.
In the local project, it is returns empty array again and again. I checked query on the robomongo, it returns null over there too. I checked manually there are 6 docs matching  but query doesnt find them

Comment: @TanerTunçer yes very weird, in my local, with robomongo i can see the documents, can you share your documents you're trying to run query on?

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/MPxqZw.png and the query https://i.hizliresim.com/QZaRBn.png I can't understand what's going wrong here

Comment: @TanerTunçer got the issue updated the answer, https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1GF0ErYNEk